# Initialize dictionary with value (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have model with Dictionary, that I want to initialize with default value
Here is how I do it now

```
 public Dictionary<string, string> controllableProperties =  new Dictionary<string, string> {
         {"controllableProperties", [{"name": "Reboot","type": {"@class": "com.avispl.symphony.api.dal.dto.control.AdvancedControllableProperty$Button","gracePeriod": "120000","labelPressed": "Rebooting..."}}]}
        };
```

But value is not string

I tried like this

```
  public Dictionary<string, string> controllableProperties =  new Dictionary<string, string> {
     {"controllableProperties", "[{"name": "Reboot","type": {"@class": "com.avispl.symphony.api.dal.dto.control.AdvancedControllableProperty$Button","gracePeriod": "120000","labelPressed": "Rebooting..."}}]"}
    };
```

But it still wrong

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Your syntax isn't valid for collection initializers and `Dictionary<string, string>` isn't a json to recognize square brackets

Comment: Okay, how I can make it right?
Cause I need JSON with `"` in value @PavelAnikhouski

Comment: @EugeneSukh you need to escape your json string. basically replacing all `"` inside with `\"`

Comment: U should look into json [deserialisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)

Comment: I tried like this ` public Dictionary<string, string> controllableProperties =  new Dictionary<string, string> {
         {"controllableProperties", "[{\"name\": \"Reboot\",\"type\": {\"@class\": \"com.avispl.symphony.api.dal.dto.control.AdvancedControllableProperty$Button\",\"gracePeriod\": \"120000\",\"labelPressed\": vRebooting...\"}}]"}
        };`

But now I get JSON with `\"` @GuruStron

Comment: @EugeneSukh how do you get json?

Comment: @GuruStron  I don’t get it. I need to hardcode it

Comment: @EugeneSukh you wrote " But now I get JSON". How do you get it?

Comment: When I send this string to api, I see \” @GuruStron

Comment: @EugeneSukh where do you see them? Have you tried to `Console/Debug.WriteLine` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `"` in your string. One approach would be to replace them with `\"`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> controllableProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {
        "controllableProperties",
        "[{\"name\": \"Reboot\",\"type\": {\"@class\": \"com.avispl.symphony.api.dal.dto.control.AdvancedControllableProperty$Button\",\"gracePeriod\": \"120000\",\"labelPressed\": \"Rebooting...\"}}]"
    }
};
Console.WriteLine(controllableProperties.Values.First()); // prints [{"name": "Reboot","type": {"@class": "com.avispl.symphony.api.dal.dto.control.AdvancedControllableProperty$Button","gracePeriod": "120000","labelPressed": "Rebooting..."}}]
```